# Skip duplicates for EMR

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, text

I currently have enormous amount of medical records which consists medical terms that need to be translated. For cost consideration, we don't want to translate every term for each record. For example, if we found the terms in a record are already frequently appeared in previous records which means these terms might be translated already in previous record, then we don't want to translate them again. I was asked to design a program to accomplish this goal. Hints I got is that I may need to break the records to alphabet level, and matrix may needed to solve this problem. I am literally a beginner in programming. Therefore, I'm looking for help here. Brutal thoughts/suggestions are enough for now. Thanks.

**[Edit by Spektre] moved from comments**

My problem boils down to this:

Say there are two sentences `A` and `B`. `A` has `m` tokens `(a1, a2, ……, am)` and `B` has `n` tokens `(b1, b2, ……, bn)`. While `A` and `B` might have common tokens. So I need a function to estimate the likelihood of tokens in B that not covered by A.

The tokens are already stored in dictionary.

How to implement this?

Comment: you did not ask a specific question. (more like not ask at all) so what kind of answer you expect?  You should be much more specific. Like  add a sample input and wanted output ... describe where exactly you're stuck. add the problematic code and describe what is wrong with it or what have you tried  etc ... But I would start to implement a dictionary which counts your words occurence ... that will give you insigt how much it is used ..  btw this sounds more like DBS problem how are your records stored ? Its a database, its a folder full of text files or what?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I misunderstood my job. You are right about the dictionary structure. Which has been already implemented in the project. My question is how can I implement a function that estimate the likelihood of tokens in a list which not appear in other lists. Say there are two sentences. A and B. A has m tokens (a1, a2, ……, am). B has n tokens (b1, b2, ……, bn). While A and B might have common tokens. So I need a function to estimate the likelihood of tokens in B that not covered by A. Thank you.

Comment: it was just comment not answer yet :). I moved your new info into your question so it does not get closed and re-tag slightly. You could do the same by hitting the edit button on the bottom left of your question.  Still a sample input and wanted output would be a good Idea to add and also language you are translating from and into as you need to take in mind also the grammar of the input and output words/text. I added answer with simple approach how I see your problem (but due to lack of sample input/output I might be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I see it right you want to know if `bi` is not in `A`.

I do not code in python but I see it like this (in **C++** like languages)

```cpp
bool untranslated(int j,int m,int n,string *a,string *b)
    {
    // the dictionaries are: a[m],b[n]
    for (int i=0;j<m;i++)   // inspect all tokens of A
     if (b[j]==a[i])        // if b[j] present in A
      return false;
    return true;
    }
```

Now if the dictionaries are rather large then you need to change this linear search to **binary search**. Also to speed up (if the words are big) you need to use hashes (**hash map**) for matching. Of coarse depending on your language you can not compare words naively with `==` rather implement some function that will convert the **word** into its **simplex grammatical form** and store to dictionary just that. That can be pretty complicated to implement.

Now the probability of whole sentence would be:

```cpp
// your dictionaries:
const int m=?,n=?;   
string A[m],string B[n]; 
// code:
int j; float p;
for (p=0.0,j=0;j<n;j++)             // test all words of B
 if (untranslated(j,m,n,A,B)) p++;   // and count how many are untranslated
p/=float(n); // normalize p to <0,1> its your probability that sentence B is not in A
```

the resulting probability `p` is in range `<0,1>` so if you want percentage instead just multiply it by `100`.

**[Edit1] occurrence of `bi`**

that is entirely different problem but also solvable relatively easy. Its the same as computing histogram so:

1. **add counter for each word in `A` dictionary**

   so each record of A will be like this:

   ```cpp
   struct A_record
    {
    string word;
    int cnt;
    };

   int m=0;
   A_record a[];
   ```
2. **process `B` sentences**

   on each word `bi` look into dictionary `A`. If not present there add it to dictionary and set its counter to `1`. If present then just increment its counter by one instead.

   ```cpp
   const int n=?;     // input sentence word count
   string b[n]={...}; // input sentence words
   int i,j;
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)  // process B
    for (j=0;j<m;j++) // search in A (should be binary search or has-map search)
     if (b[i]==a[j].word)
      {  a[j].cnt++; j=-1; break; } // here a[j].cnt is the bi occurrence you wanted if divided by m then its probability <0,1>
   if (j<0)
    { a[m].word=b[i]; a[m].cnt=1; m++; } // here no previous occurrence of bi
   ```

   Now if you want just previous occurrence of `bi`then look at the matched `a[j].cnt` during the search. If you want the occurrence of any `b[i]` word in whole text look at the same counter after whole text is processed.

Comment: I appreciate your help:)

Comment: Hi, I was busy in doing something else this days, so I just checked your code. If I understand right, your code did calculate the percentage of a record that have not been translated. While the probability I need which is the number of appearance for a term among all records divide by the number of records. Say the example I made early.  String B is the record I currently work with, and b1 is the token I do want know the probability of. So I need a function to find out how many times b1 has appeared in previous records.

Comment: Subsequently, I can use this number divide by the number of records to find out the probability of occurrence for a certain term I guess. But thank you for your code and I'm so sorry for my awful description that wasted your time:(

Comment: @Eason well your wording of Question and comments suggested problem I answered. Anyway I added [edit1] with your current problem ... You should edit your question so its clear What you are asking about ...